# Speed-up product and summation of multi-dimensional lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I am solving some equilibrium equations using Newton iterations over many increments. At each iteration, I need to evaluate Jacobian matrix (tangent stiffness). Its submatrices are defined through numerical integration of product *m1.m3.m2*, where each matrix *mi* is multi-dimensional list of lists. Due to the nature of the problem, utilized matrices *m1*, *m2*, *m3* could be sparse, but not guaranteed.
I have tried to conceive this as a minimal example. List *indices* is, in my code, defined with specific function, and here it is generated through some random integer seeding. The bottleneck is calculating the *list* matrix (these are submatrices of my stiffness matrix). As mentioned, they follow from summation of matrix products *m1.m3.m2*, where only elements that exist in indices list are considered.
If it helps, *m1* and *m2* matrices are fixed (and sometimes equal *m1*=*m2*) during the iterations, while only *m3* matrix changes through iterations.
Unfortunately, for some required values of *e1*, *p1*, *e2*, *p2* (approximately up to 50-100) the computational time blows up. Any help regarding the performance tuning is appreciated.

```
e1 = 20;
p1 = 20;
e2 = 20;
p2 = 20;

active1 = RandomInteger[{1, e1}];
active2 = RandomInteger[{1, p1}, {e1}];
active3 = RandomInteger[{1, e2}, {e1}];
active4 = RandomInteger[{1, p2}, {e2}];


indices = 
  Table[DeleteDuplicates[
    Table[{k, RandomInteger[{1, active2[[k]]}], m, 
      RandomInteger[{1, active4[[m]]}]}, {RandomInteger[{1, 
        e1*e2}]}]], {k, 1, active1}, {m, 1, active3[[k]]}];


m1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {e1, p1, e2, p2, 2, 10}];
m2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {e1, p1, e2, p2, 2, 10}];
m3 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {e1, p1, e2, p2, 2, 2}];

list = Table[0, {e1}, {e2}];

Table[Table[
   list[[i, j]] = 
    Sum[Transpose[
       m1[[co[[1]], co[[2]], co[[3]], co[[4]]]]].m3[[co[[1]], co[[2]],
         co[[3]], co[[4]]]].m2[[co[[1]], co[[2]], co[[3]], 
        co[[4]]]], {co, indices[[i, j]]}], {j, active3[[i]]}], {i, 
   active1}];
```

Comment: Please, use `RandomReal[{0,1},{e1,p1,e2,p2,2,10}]` instead of `Table[RandomReal[], {e1}, {p1}, {e2}, {p2}, {2}, {10}]`.